# Text to speech - How to parse the SSML string in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tvos

I am getting a SSML text in the JSON and trying to find out a standard way to parse this SSML format i.e

```
"text" : [ "<speak>Screen title <break strength='weak '/> Sign In <break strength='weak '/> </speak>" ]
```

for my tts application. But I find no way except doing manually. I need to fetch out the real string to be played using AVSpeechSynthesizer. Has anyone tried this before? Help!

Currently it is uttering the complete text->value with tags.

Comment: How about a regular expression?

Comment: Ok, let me try that.

Comment: You can use any Speech Synthesis libraries to convert SSML strings.

Comment: Can you suggest more on this? AVSpeechSynthesis should not read SSML tags, the other way is to use regex which seems to be only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it using the regular expression to parse SSML tags as suggested by @Carpsen90. There is no other way I found. But, thanks for all your help!

Comment: can you share the RegEx you used?